# Vuex computed property not updating

Tags: vuejs2, vuex, getter

I am having a hard time trying to update my component state based off a reference Id that I am using to display a result that lives in my store/vuex. Basically, what I want to happen is for when I update a reference ID, my getters/computed passes down the updates value. I have provided a simple version of what I am trying to do with no luck. Any ideas?

What am I doing wrong?

**Parent Component file**

```
<template>
 <div class="parent"
   <Car :car="car" />
   <div class="car-btn" @click="switchCarId('11')" >Change Car</div>
 </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex';
import Car from './Car.vue';
export default {
  name: 'Car',
  components: { Car },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters(['car'])
  },
  methods: {
    switchCarId(val) {
      this.$store.commit('updateCarReferenceId', val);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

**Child Component file**

```
<template>
 <div class="car">{{ car.name }} </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Car',
  props: { 'car': Object }
};
</script>
```

**Store file**

```
import Vuex from 'vuex';
Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    selectedCarId: '10',
    cars: {
      '10': {
        name: 'Red Car'
      },
      '11': {
        name: 'Blue Car'
      }
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    updateCarReferenceId(state, val) {
      state.selectedCarId = val;
    }
  },
  getters: {
    car: (state, getters) => {
      return getters.cars[getters.getSelectedCarId];
    },
    cars: (state) => {
      return state.cars;
    },
    getSelectedCarId: (state) => {
      return state.selectedCarId;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: did you look at the store in VueJs DevTools?

Comment: any errors or warnings in console?

Comment: Yes, according to Vue dev inspector, the mutation gets called and set. But my computed property doesn't filter back through.

Comment: all seems to be fine. Can you create an example on jsfiddle or codepen?

Comment: I think I helped narrow this issue down. Thanks for the extra jog @anatoly. My sample isn't fully accurate to what I am doing. I tried to over simplify it but by doing that I removed part of the issue. I am passing `car` into a child component as a prop. And this child component is reading this prop. This child component is not updating.

Comment: And if you add watch on 'car' with immediate: true and console.log with a new and an old values in a child component what you'll get?

Comment: It returns correctly. It just not pushing down into the Child component.

Comment: So you see an old prop value in a child component via VueJs DevTools?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue. Turns out deep down in a component I was change changing the value based on a input. So no matter what the state read, it only read it initially. Thanks to Anoatoly for helping me run through it and making sure I dotted my t's and crossing my i's.